# Android Toggle image on click on the image inside listview

Tags: android, listview, toggle

I have a `listview` which has as image and a text.
Bases on conditions i have set two different images for the text views.
To set the images i have used

```
viewholder.btnFavItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagA);
```

Now on click i want toggle the images. if initially it was image a, i want it to becomes image b.
I have used the `onclick listner` and not the on item click becoz i need the position of image and the textview.I need the position becoz the textview can have either of the two images.the one that has image a,i want to change that to image b. i am clicking on the image and not the tetxview. i have used a custom adapter which extends base adapter.

in the onclick i am again using

```
viewholder.btnFavItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagB);
```

In the xml i have used clickable as true and focusable as false.

how do i toggle these images.

Answer (score 2):

What you can actually do is use a tag to your image via setTag(), and compare it with your getTag():

```
String tag = viewholder.btnFavItem.getTag();
if(tag.equals("imagA"))
{
    viewholder.btnFavItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagB);
    viewholder.btnFavItem.setTag("imagB");
}
else if(tag.equals("imagB"))
{
    viewholder.btnFavItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagA);
    viewholder.btnFavItem.setTag("imagA");
}
```